# Laravel 5.8 uploading an image

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, upload

I want to upload an image in the profile page.

I created create.blade.php for profile page.

After filling in the blank, I want to show each information, image, name, gender, country, bod, description in index.blade.php.

> Now I could insert all the data except an image.

I have already executed **php artisan storage:link**

So I am appreciate if someone gives me a hand.

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('profile', 'UserController');
});
```

**migration file**

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('bod');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

create.blade.php

```
<div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->image))
                <img src="{{asset('image/image1.jpg')}}" class="image-preview__image">
                @else
                <img src="{{asset('uploads/profile')}}/{{Auth::user()->profile->image}}" class="image-preview__image">
                @endif
        </div>

        <form action="{{ route('profile.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
        <div class="preview">
                <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
            <label for="file">
                Change Image
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul class="information">
            <li>Name :<br>
                <input type="text" class="name" name="name" required
                value="@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->name)){{ Auth::user()->profile->name }}@endif">
            </li><br>
            <li>Gender :<br>
                <div class="gender">
                    <select name="gender" id="" name="gender" >
                        <option class="option" value="@if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->gender))Select Gender
                                @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->gender }}@endif" selected="selected" required>
                                @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->gender))Select Gender
                                @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->gender }}@endif
                        </option>
                        <option value="male" >male</option> 
                        <option value="female" class="selected">female</option> 
                        <option value="any">any</option> 
                    </select>       
                </div>
            </li>   
            <li>Country :<br>
                <div class="country">
                    <select name="country" id="" name="country" required>
                            <option class="option" value="@if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->country))Select country
                                    @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->country }}@endif" selected="selected">

                                    @if(empty(Auth::user()->profile->country))Select country
                                    @else{{ Auth::user()->profile->country }}@endif
                            </option>
                        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                        <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>    
            </li><br>
            <li>Birthday :<br>
                <input type="text" class="birthday" id="bod" name="bod" 
                value="@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->bod)){{ Auth::user()->profile->bod }}@endif">
            </li><br>
            <li>User Description :<br>
                <textarea name="description" id="" cols="60" rows="10">@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->description)){{ Auth::user()->profile->description }}@endif</textarea></li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" class="saveBtn">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

UserController.php

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'image'=>'image|mimes:png, jpg, jpeg|max:20000'
        ]);

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
            $file->move('uploads/profile/', $filename);
            Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
                'image'=>$filename
            ]);
        }

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'bod'=>'required|before:today'
        ]);

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        Profile::updateOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => $user_id], // search requirements
            [   
                'name' => request('name'),
                'gender' => request('gender'),
                'country' => request('country'),
                'bod' => request('bod'),
                'description' => request('description')
            ]
        );
        return redirect()->route('profile.index')->with('profile', Profile::all());
    }
```

Comment: I am thinking path is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.No need to assign this first,just store it later

```
Profile::updateOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => $user_id], // search requirements
            [   
                'name' => $request->name,

                'description' => $request->description,
                'image'=>$filename
            ]
        );
```

please change your validation for birhdate..it's your problem to update.give a date format then it will work

```
'bod'=>'date_format:Y-m-d|before:today'
```

Comment: i run your code properly & it's work for me...change your validation for birthdate.  'bod'=>'date_format:Y-m-d|before:today'

Comment: Thank you so much ! First I removed image validation, then I followed your answer and it worked !